# Auto log off on mac even when account is active

Tags: macos, imac

is there any way to automatically log off a guest account after 10 minutes of login? I want to log out of the account every 10 minutes immaterial of whether it is active or inactive. Is there a way to accomplish that on Mac?

Comment: You can try something from [this](http://superuser.com/questions/40061/what-is-the-mac-os-x-terminal-command-to-log-out-the-current-user) answer and a bash script in a `While True` loop, including sleep 600 for the 10 minute delay

Comment: did you try the parietal controls ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 I tried parental controls and it has an option only if the user is inactive.

Comment: @Mathias711 I am not familiar with apple programming so I dont really know how to write a bash script.